# Parent focus lost when child changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am focusing a div to listen to a `keydown` event on it and I have a wrapper like this:

```
class Wrapper extends react.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs["profilebody"].focus();
    this.refs["profilebody"].addEventListener(
      "keydown",
      this.props.onOverlayKeyDown,
      false
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    /// removing even listerner
  }

  render() {
    <div className="modal_container" tabIndex="-1" ref={"profilebody"}>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

And in the parent say WrapperParent I am changing the children.

```
class WrapperParent extends React.component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {{
          [`render-a`]: <A />,
          [`render-b`]: <B />
        }}
        [this.state.screen]}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

> NOTE: the children is always a React element

The problem is whenever I am changing the children in the parent the focus is going to body instead of staying at the specified div.

How do I make focus stay on the div?